# Creating URL like CNN Article URL in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I need to create a URL format in CodeIgniter that is somewhat similar to the CNN Article URL format.

http://edition.cnn.com/2012/08/17/world/asia/australia-assange-asylum-ecuador/index.html?hpt=hp_c2

The interesting part is of course the **year/month/day/section_name/article_name**. I was able to recreate the date for testing, and ended up with this sort of url:

**http://localhost/myapplication/index.php/2012/08/17/1**

where the last "1" is the article ID.

The issue is that my controller's view function only needs the 4th parameter (the article ID) to retrieve the article, and all the other parameters are ignored. As such, 2014/06/11/1 would result in the same page, since the article ID is the same.

What occurred to me is that I could, in my view function, retrieve the article date (since I'm retrieving the article data from the db anyway), and double check it against the URL to make sure that the URL's date is valid. I'm just wondering if this is the correct practice, since I would eventually have to do the same against section title and article title...

Comment: And what is the question here? You want to place the title in the URL? Or what?

Comment: Google [`codeigniter sef urls`](http://www.google.com/search?q=codeigniter+sef+urls)

Comment: The question is what is the best practice to achieve this. Should I manually check on the date part of the URL to make sure that the article date (although the article itself was definitely returned since the ID is correct) matches? And then when I add the section title and article name, should I also be checking manually on those as well? Or is there some other way this can be done?

Comment: I think if you did the date part already, then yes, check for it, or it's depending on. Is it a problem for you, if in the url the date didn't match the article date?

Comment: DaveRandom that's great for creating the URL, which is something I already know how to do. My question is what happens behind this URL. Do I have to manually double check every parameter to see if it matches my article, although the only real parameter I need is the ID? If you have a specific link that can help me with that I'd be grateful.

Comment: @AndrásRátz If you check CNN, if you change just one letter in the section name, it will give you page invalid. So I'm wondering whether I'm going at it the right way (using the ID and keep all the other parameters ignored but just for SEF purposes).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think now I'm getting, what you mean.

You create the url and then, you get the document from the database by id, or more SEF if you use slugs. If you store the date  as date type in mysql ( if you are using mysql ), then it's easier to write it in the sql query too and every other criteria, like section name.

Comment: Do you think I should put the entire string (date/section/articlename) as a slug in the database, and retrieve the article accordingly? Also wouldn't that affect select query performance in a table with 100,000+ items?

Comment: No, i thought only the article name, because you wrote, you want to use slug. Then search for the slug, with the given date.